# Will using LIMIT OFFSET with SUM provide accurate data?

Tags: database, postgresql

I believe I a fairly simple question that I can not locate here on Stack or out in Google land.  I have a fairly basic select statment that's something like this:

```
SELECT
    itemid,
    itemdiscription,
    SUM(quantity)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY itemid, itemdescription
ORDER BY itemid
LIMIT    250
OFFSET   0;
```

Basicly this is pulling from a table of over 100k + records or so, or less depending, it's a temporary table.  So what I'm trying to figure out is the SUM function providing reliable data, because there could 30k records between similar item ids.  My initial thought was this would preform the query and then return only the first 250 results, but then I got to thinking maybe not, so I thought I'd ask the community for comfirmation on how this works.

The main reason I'm using LIMIT/OFFSET is because I'm preforming the query from PHP and those values are variables that are iterated for preformance so I'm not dealing with an Array that uses mass amounts of memory.

Thanks!

Comment: The entire sum operation will be performed, and then only the final result set will be affected by the `limit / offset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs state, the limit (or offset) apply to "the rows that are generated by the rest of the query", so consider the result of the query prior to the application of limit or offset. Applying these clauses then affects these results.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-limit.html

Here's a SQL Fiddle of a couple of ways of using LIMIT

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/08fa0

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted be 100% sure and didn't have enough test data to confirm.  Thanks for the Fiddle link as well!  I think that'll come in handy :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, LIMIT works on top of query result after it has been processed. However, server can optimize this if it believes that outcome will be identical - for example, `SELECT x FROM t ORDER BY x LIMIT 1` will work very fast if `x` is indexed field.

But, if you are using LIMIT/OFFSET here for performance or to implement paging, you should rethink your approach. This is because even if all aggregated fields are indexed and LIMIT can take advantage of that, when OFFSET increases, total work increases as well and soon runtime becomes almost the same as running full query without LIMIT - very expensive.

If you are going to keep OFFSET very low (preferably 0), I would highly recommend adding compound index on `(itemid,itemdescription)` - it should make your query to run much faster, especially if you have many rows with the same `itemid`.

Comment: The preformance issue is when I try to store 100k plus records of 75 columns and values into a single array in php, to then be looped through so that the data can be manipulated and then displayed in a web app.  The memory required to hold that array is too high for the php web server.  Granted I could increase the max memory per session available, but that would still cause issues once multiple users are interfacing at the same time.  So I'm limiting the size of the php array by limitng the records returned.  Other wise I would have prefered getting all the data at once.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN` your query to see, how it is executed. You will see, that `LIMIT` is applied after grouping.